# GAE: Specify min_instances only for default service version

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

We have a service running on Google App Engine.
If that service does not receive a traffic for some time then all instances are killed and the next call takes a few additional seconds to start the application.
We are thinking about specifying a min_instances option in `app.yaml` to always keep at least one instance alive.

We deploy new versions of that service quite frequently and keeping old versions for some time. Those old versions are not serving traffic and kept just in case.

What we would like to do is to always keep at least one instance of default service version alive and leave all other non-default versions with default behavior – we want them to be scaled automatically to 0 instances if they do not receive any traffic.

I didn't find such option in the documentation (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref#scaling_elements) and didn't come to any workarounds.

I am thinking about creating a cron job (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml) which will periodically "ping" only default version of my application periodically thus making it always asleep. But I am not sure if it is good solution.

Are there any better solutions to such case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

min_idle_instances config option seems to solve my problem.
Note following in the documentation: "This setting only applies to the version that receives most of the traffic" which is almost exactly my case:

```
automatic_scaling:
    min_idle_instances: 1
```

Comment: Sure, but also in the documentation it states that : "Note that you are charged for the number of instances specified whether they are receiving traffic or not". So you'll be charged for 2 instances if there is any traffic and for one instance if there's not any traffic.

Comment: I think the cron job solution that you shared would be definitely less cheaper than this.